# C++ How to avoid from cyclic inclusion?

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I have two classes.

First **A.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
    A(B* pair) :myPair(pair){};
    void checkPair();
private:
    B* myPair;
};

void A::checkPair()
{
    myPair->checkPair();
}

#endif
```

Second **B.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "A.h"

class B
{
public:
    B(A* pair) :myPair(pair){};
    void checkPair();
private:
    A* myPair;
};

void B::checkPair()
{
    myPair->checkPair();
}

#endif
```

The Compiler tells me that he can't identify class A in B.h file.
Is there any solutions for cyclic inclusion problems like this?

Comment: Yes, forward declare instead of including. And move implementations out of the header.

Comment: Probably is a duplicate of something, but that question already knew about forward declaration.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry about this question. I understood that this question is already asked.

Answer (score 1):

In `A.h` file instead of including `B.h` use forward declaration:

```
class B;
```